# Is there really no alternative to localeconv() in PHP, which doesn't depend on the "current locale"?

Tags: php

I'm trying to grab locale data for a given locale/region in PHP. The only way that you can do this appears to be to use `localeconv()`, which returns data for the **currently used** locale, as determined with `setlocale()`. But...

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

> Warning The locale information is maintained per process, not per
>   thread. If you are running PHP on a multithreaded server API like IIS,
>   HHVM or Apache on Windows, you may experience sudden changes in locale
>   settings while a script is running, though the script itself never
>   called setlocale(). This happens due to other scripts running in
>   different threads of the same process at the same time, changing the
>   process-wide locale using setlocale().

This is completely unacceptable. I can't have other scripts changing locales randomly because a *different* script is temporarily calling `setlocale()` just to be able to make `localeconv()` dump the right data. This is what has made me never use the built-in locale-sensitive features in PHP, instead painstakingly looking up the info myself and hardcoding it into my own library, bypassing all the convenience of just setting a locale.

Is there really no other way to get that data?